# How to pin the edit toolbar in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sitepages

I have a problem using the SharePoint in the site I am working on. I have a big banner in the head of the page so when I try to edit the content of the page I have to scroll down to select the part to be edited and then scroll up to get access to the edit toolbar and so on up and down.

Is there any way I can pin the toolbar so I don't have to go up and down?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of "toolbar" you are talking about? Are you talking about web part toolbar? If yes, unfortunately you cannot pin it using SharePoint default functionalities.